# C++ - Uniform initializer with std::string

Tags: c++, string, c++11, uniform-initialization, list-initialization

I am trying the uniform intializer with the string class of C++. Below is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string str1 {"aaaaa"};
    string str2 {5, 'a'};
    string str3 (5, 'a');

    cout << "str1: " << str1 << endl;
    cout << "str2: " << str2 << endl;
    cout << "str3: " << str3 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output would be:

```
str1: aaaaa
str2: a
str3: aaaaa
```

This made me scratched my head. Why `str2` cannot achieved the desired result as `str3`?

Comment: "Uniform" initialization...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) has a constructor that takes an `initializer_list` argument.

```
basic_string( std::initializer_list<CharT> init,
              const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

That constructor always gets precedence when you use a *braced-init-list* to construct `std::string`. The other constructors are only considered if the elements in the *braced-init-list* are not convertible to the type of elements in the `initializer_list`. This is mentioned in [[over.match.list]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.list#1).

> Initially, the candidate functions are the initializer-list constructors ([dcl.init.list]) of the class `T` and the argument list consists of the initializer list as a single argument.

In your example, the first argument `5` is implicitly convertible to `char`, so the `initializer_list` constructor is viable, and it gets chosen.

This is evident if you print each character in the strings as `int`s

```
void print(char const *prefix, string& s)
{
    cout << prefix << s << ", size " << s.size() << ": ";
    for(int c : s) cout << c << ' ';
    cout << '\n';
}

string str1 {"aaaaa"};
string str2 {5, 'a'};
string str3 (5, 'a');

print("str1: ", str1);
print("str2: ", str2);
print("str3: ", str3);
```

Output:

```
str1: aaaaa, size 5: 97 97 97 97 97 
str2: a, size 2: 5 97 
str3: aaaaa, size 5: 97 97 97 97 97
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e270f7162f9788b0)

Comment: Thanks. Kind of got the idea what is going on here. I always prefer the uniform initialization since I was told it is the best practise from now on (I am still new to C++). Looks like I got to be careful from now on.

Comment: @Hilman As you've found out, it doesn't always work so *uniformly*. With `vector<int>` for instance, `vector<int> v1{4,2}, v2(4,2);`. Here `v1` contains 2 integers, 4 and 2, while `v2` contains 4 integers, each initialized to 2.

Answer (score 10):

You are using [`std::string`'s constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) with this siganture

```
std::basic_string( std::initializer_list<CharT> init, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

And the compiler treated `5` as a `char` type, which translates to an `ASCII` type that isn't printed on screen. If you change that `5` to a printable value, say `A` whose ASCII value is `65`,

```
string str2 {65, 'a'};
```

it will print:

```
Aa
```

See it [Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5d4fd3d3c48c135d) with an additional illustration