# std::string(count, ch) not called when using uniform initialization

Tags: c++, string, c++11, uniform-initialization

I just got caught by this seemingly innocent attempt to call the [`std::string` constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) that takes a size and a character value, using uniform initialization syntax:

```
std::string s{ 10, '\0' };
```

I thought this would create a string with the length of 10, initialized with `\0`.

Though it actually calls the constructor that takes an **initializer list** and thus creates a string with the **length of 2**, initialized with `{'\n', '\0'}`!

See [demo at Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/97b3d83a17d3b3f3).

Is there a way to avoid this pitfall when using uniform initialization? Or do I just have to be careful?

**Note:** [Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38809275/7571258) has been asked before, but no answer was given on how to avoid that pitfall.

Comment: I think the wikipedia entry on [uniform initialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Uniform_initialization) describes it nicely: "Uniform initialization does not replace constructor syntax, which is still needed at times. If a class has an initializer list constructor (`TypeName(initializer_list<SomeType>);`), then it takes priority over other forms of construction, provided that the initializer list conforms to the sequence constructor's type."

Comment: @clcto Compiler seems to be eager to use initializer list constructor, even if the list consist of non-conforming types ([Coliru example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/67a7386717f5b1ef)). To be fair there is a compiler warning.

Comment: @zett42: For the record, that behaviour is guaranteed by `[over.match.list]/1`; basically; constructors are looked up in two phases and if any initializer-list constructors exist at all then that's what you get, for better or for worse.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just have to be careful.

In general, when people tell you to "use uniform initialisation so that everything is consistent and, well, *uniform*", **ignore them**. I mean, by all means use uniform initialisation, but don't believe that fairytale.

Also, ignore the name of the feature.

[image: xkcd #927: "Standards"]

Comment: Well, the feature isn't officially named "uniform initialization" in the standard (or unicorn, for that matter).

Comment: To be fair, list initialization didn't *have* to work out this way. It *could* have subsumed all forms of initialization, if the committee had not make two mistakes: the preference for `initializer_list` constructors and forbidding narrowing conversions. Remove both of those, and you could legitimately replace any case of `()` initialization with `{}`.